# Get application active time

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to check how much time I spent in application (on foreground or background)? I would like display this data in my app. Any idea?

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I did research but I haven't found any interesting solution. These few sentences in the question describe the whole problem.

Comment: From [ask]… "Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, _including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others_ in understanding how your question is different from the rest.". Show your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. But you have to do some time calculations. First of all you need 2 delegates from 'AppDelegate' -

```
1.func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
2.func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

- Now you need to save the time stamp when the app will about to enter in the forground and also another time stamp when the app in gone to background. You can save these 2 times in the app userdefaults.
- After that create a function / class which will return you the time difference of 'Forground' time and 'background' time.

> - The difference between *"applicationWillEnterForeground"* and "*applicationDidEnterBackground*" is your = **APP ACTIVE TIME**
> - and The difference between *"applicationDidEnterBackground"* and "*applicationWillEnterForeground*" is your = **APP BACKGROUND TIME**

Answer (score 0):

1. Get current time in [`application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623032-application) and save it to persistent storage
2. Get current time in [`applicationWillTerminate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

The difference between this two times will be the the time application was working.

To get current time use `let currTime = Date()`

You can use [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) as a simplest persistent storage.

---

More information on application lifecycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle)